# Install custom font on linux (windows AddFontResource equivalent)

Tags: c++, linux

How to install custom font on linux, either directly from C++ or using [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) command?
I mean some way like [AddFontResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183326(v=vs.85).aspx) in windows.

Comment: Do you want to install the font for console or X?

Comment: Just for X, to be usable for example in [zenity](https://help.gnome.org/users/zenity/stable/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the workflow to distribute and run your program. If it's a software package which is installed by a system administrator, then a font should be placed into a system font directory (usually, a directory under `/usr/share/fonts/`, e.g. `/usr/share/fonts/ttf/`) when the package is being installed. If the program is being installed by an unprivileged user, then the font file should go into `$HOME/.fonts/` directory.

If the font is installed system-wide then it [automagically] appears in the system (a typical Linux distribution already has appropriate hooks in the package management subsystem to rebuild font caches). If the font is installed "manually" (e.g. a user simply copies a file into her `$HOME/.fonts/`) then invocation of `fc-cache --force` may be required.

A more detailed explanation: fonts in a modern Linux installation are managed by a subsystem called [fontconfig](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/). This subsystem has system-wide configuration (by default residing in `/etc/fonts/fonts.conf` and `/etc/fonts/conf.d/`) and per-user configuration ([various locations](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/fontconfig/fontconfig-user.html) are checked). Fontconfig maintains the cache of all fonts registered in the system. When one wishes to register another font, he or she puts the font file into one of the directories known to `fontconfig` and initiates a rebuild of the cache w/ `fc-cache` utility. If the font is installed system-wide, then the packaging system typically has appropriate hooks which call `fc-cache` automatically when a file being created or deleted in a "well-known font directory".